# Copy console.log json output to clipboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in one of the browsers to just copy the output of console.log?  When mocking an object for Angular unit tests, I output a real data set with `console.log(myObject)` and would like to be able to just get the object on my clipboard to paste it into my unit test.  I saw an answer on how to print out to a file in chrome, but that's probably overkill for me at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, you can just copy it. That won't always work for large, complex objects. You can also use `JSON.stringify` to force string output:

```
var foo = {"bar":"baz"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```